# Ruby on Rails assign variable from nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a simple paycheck calculator.  I have assigned most of the variables for calculation like this:
        `@hours = params[:hours].to_i`
I created a model for the states and created a dropdown box with:
        `<%= collection_select(:state, :abbr, State.all, :abbr, :abbr) %>`
This seems to work as I want.  The problem I am having is assigning the selected state to a variable. Below is the debug(params):

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  hours: '80'
  rate: '15'
  allowances: '1'
  marital_status: S
  pay_period: '1'
  state: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    abbr: AL
  commit: Submit
  controller: calc_page
  action: home
permitted: false
```

I don't know if this is an error in syntax or I am completely missing something.  I have tried:
    `@state = params[:state["abbr"]]`
    `@state = params[:state]["abbr"]`
among many others.

Any advice or guidance is appreciated or if i need to provide more information.

Thanks.

Comment: `params[:state][:abbr]` should work

Comment: could you add top of the log for this action, where request/params are shown?

Comment: `@state = params[:state]["abbr"]` should also work, as they are hashes with indifferent access.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to access any nested params, for example

```
a:
 b:
  c: "hello"
```

then **params[:a][:b][:c]** will give you output "hello".
In your case **params[:state][:abbr]** will do the work.